# Chamar ajax por onclick em SWAL

Tags: ajax

Olá, estou tentando fazer com que após o usuário clicar em um botão, abra um SWAL contendo outro botão que tem uma função ajax, porém, nem o SWAL abre.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var encerrar = $('#encerrar');
  $('input').on('click', function () {
      encerrar();
  })

        swal({
                title: "Tem certeza?",
                text: "Realmente quer encerrar o atendimento?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Sim",
                closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function encerrar()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Back/encerrar.php",
                                success: function(data){
                                }
            }).
            done(function(data) {
                 swal("Canceled!", "Your order was successfully canceled!", "success");
                 $('#orders-history').load(document.URL +  ' #orders-history');
             })
             .error(function(data) {
                 swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
             });
         });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Na linha abaixo, você especificou um nome para a função, a função deve ser anonima.

```
}, function encerrar(){
```

Deve ser assim:

```
}, function(){
```

Comment: O erro permanece

Comment: verifica no console do seu navegador, se ao clicar em "Sim", aparece algum erro. Poste esse erro aqui!

Comment: Esse é o ponto, não aparece o SWAL! Eu clico no botão (compareceu) e não acontece absolutamente nada

Comment: Cara você não fez a chamada do SWAL,tenta assim: https://jsfiddle.net/n45wvL4d/

Comment: Nada, inclusive não funcionou no jsfiddle

Comment: Era pra você copiar apenas o HTML, não tem como rodar por lá pois não tem como rodar uma biblioteca externa por lá.